# Static variables passing across the php files

Tags: java, php

i would like to pass a static variable across different php files,one of my collegue working in java have implemented it as follows 
1.create a class
2.declare the variable as static final
3.where ever we want to access this variable value is  did by classname.varaiablename

I wanted to do the same in php 
here i have my code ,i have more than 24 files in my project and i want this variable declared as staic file in all 24 files,i dont want to use session.
i have a page 1.php
the code is as follows

```
<?php
class Foo
{
 public static $url='http://192.168.2.36:8084/';
    function GetReference() {
      return self::$url; // I want to return a reference to the static member variable.
    }

}

$Inst = new Foo;
$Ref = $Inst->GetReference();
?>
```

i have another page 2.php
where i have accessed it as

```
<?php
require_once("1.php");
echo Foo::$url;
?>
```

i am not getting the value

Answer (score 0):

just include that file in all 24 files.
[include-once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access URL as foo::$url, You need to make the static variable access specifier as public, not protected.

Comment: i have completed my code ,can any one review whether it is correct or not

Comment: include page1.php, instead of 1.php and remove "$Inst = new Foo;
$Ref = $Inst->GetReference();" from class file, else it will echo $URL  twice.